# how to change the scale of view

Tags: ios, swift, view, scale

I am trying to make sidebar menu like in app Euro Sport! When the menu slides from left , the `sourceviewcontroller` slide to left and becomes smaller.

```
var percentWidthOfContainer = containerView.frame.width * 0.2 // this is 20 percent of width

    var widthOfMenu = containerView.frame.width - percentWidthOfContainer

    bottomView.transform = self.offStage(widthOfMenu)

    bottomView.frame.origin.y = 60

    bottomView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(widthOfMenu, 400)

    bottomView.updateConstraints()

    menucontroller.view.frame.size = CGSizeMake(widthOfMenu, containerView.frame.height)

    menucontroller.updateViewConstraints()
```

Here, the bottom view is sourceviewcontroller.view. So, the question is how to scale bottom view. In my case , i can change the size but everything inside view is still in the same size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `CGAffineTransformScale` to scale instance of `UIView`

For Instance

Suppose you have an instance of `UIView` as

```
UIView *view;
```

// lets say you have instantiated and customized your view

..
..

// Keep the original transform of the view in a variable as

```
CGAffineTransform viewsOriginalTransform = view.transform;
```

// to scale down the view use `CGAffineTransformScale`

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(viewsOriginalTransform, 0.5, 0.5);
```

// again to scale up the view

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(viewsOriginalTransform, 1.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Hi, I added your code to scale view. It works but my  func offStage(amount: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform {
       return CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(amount, 0)
    } doesnt work. I cant move source view controller to left. If I put that code below transformscale, the scaling dont work

Comment: are you using CGAffineTransformScale or CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation?

Comment: I am using both! But both of them dont work together! Ok I will create another question

Comment: I found the solution, after scaling it I need to change the x coordinate of view by using view.frame.origin.x = whatever coordinate i need. thanks for replying Sanjay!

Comment: @YestayMuratov sorry I was away, yes after scaling you need to change the origin to top left / top right corner as per your requirements.

Comment: I have one more issue with menu:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480350/how-to-choose-the-right-uigesturerecognizer-swift

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple doc's

> The CGAffineTransform data structure represents a matrix used for
>   affine transformations. A transformation specifies how points in one
>   coordinate system map to points in another coordinate system. An
>   affine transformation is a special type of mapping that preserves
>   parallel lines in a path but does not necessarily preserve lengths or
>   angles. Scaling, rotation, and translation are the most commonly used
>   manipulations supported by affine transforms, but skewing is also
>   possible.

**So your solution to minimize the size of bottomView :-**

```
bottomView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2) // you can change it as per your requirement
```

**If you want to resize it or maximize it to its original size:**

```
bottomView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
```

**Just in case you want to expand the bottom view more than its size:-**

```
 bottomView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3) // you can change it as per your requirement
```

Comment: Hi, I added your code to scale view. It works but my  func offStage(amount: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform {
       return CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(amount, 0)
    } doesnt work. I cant move source view controller to left. If I put that code below transformscale, the scaling dont work

Comment: When it works, then you are asking another problem in comments that doesn't relate to your question asked i.e "the question is how to scale bottom view.the question is how to scale bottom view.". You should  accept it solution. Then ask another question for your problem

Comment: hello, I have new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480350/how-to-choose-the-right-uigesturerecognizer-swift