# How to choose the right UIGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have view controller which as UIPageViewController inside.

Using pageviewcontroller I can swipt left, right in order to go to other VCs. It works!

So, after I added sideBarMenu. When adding this menu I use this code to add gesture recognizer:

```
 var menuViewController: UIViewController! {
    didSet {
        self.exitPanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        self.exitPanGesture.addTarget(self, action:"handleOffstagePan:")
        self.sourceViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.exitPanGesture)

    }
```

Here the sourceViewController is my original VC.

The problem is when I try to swipe (in order to close menu), the pageViewController swipe works.

I want to disable pageViewController swipe and enable new swipe function when menu is opened. And do oppositely when menu is closed.

Additional code:

```
 func handleOffstagePan(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    println("dismiss pan gesture recognizer")

    let translation = pan.translationInView(pan.view!)

    let d = translation.x / CGRectGetWidth(pan.view!.bounds) * -0.5

    switch (pan.state) {

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        self.interactive = true

        self.menuViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("dismisMenu", sender: self)

        break
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
        self.updateInteractiveTransition(d)
        break
    default:
        self.interactive = false

        if d > 0.1 {

            self.finishInteractiveTransition()
        }else {

            isMenuVisible = false
            self.cancelInteractiveTransition()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: considering your problem I think at present handleOffstagePan event will not be triggering, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are! I found the solution, instead of writing sourviewcontroller = PageViewController, I wrote sourveviewcontroller = PageContentViewController. Now the gesture recognizer works. I have new problem, now I cant swipe left , right on my pageviewcontroller, I need to add the old gesture recognizer, or delete the new one I added(which closes menu)

Comment: remove the gesture recognizer which is added on the self.sourceViewController in side handleOffstagePan event

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying, instead of removing I disabled it!

Comment: that's even better solution both coding and performance wise, as it avoids the overheads of adding and removing the gesture

Answer (score 0):

Guys!
SO, the solution is instead of setting PageViewController to the sourceVC of your TransitionManager, set pageContentViewController to the sourceVC. PageContentViewControler is :

```
 func resetToMainPage(index: Int!) {
    /* Getting the page View controller */
    mainPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainPageViewController") as UIPageViewController
    self.mainPageViewController.dataSource = self
    self.mainPageViewController.delegate = self

    let pageContentViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    self.transtionManger.sourceViewController = pageContentViewController // adding swipe to the pageContentViewControlle in order to close menu

    self.mainPageViewController.setViewControllers([pageContentViewController!], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)


    self.mainPageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 102, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
    self.addChildViewController(mainPageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(mainPageViewController.view)
    self.mainPageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}
```

Here I set pageContentVC to the sourveVS of transitionManageClass. NExt how to choose the right GestureRecognizer. By default when you add new gesture recognizer the old one doesnt work. When you disable the new gesture recognizer the old one starts to work! I added new gesture recognizer using code:

```
var menuViewController: UIViewController! {
    didSet {
        self.exitPanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        self.exitPanGesture.addTarget(self, action:"handleOffstagePan:")
      //  self.exitPanGesture.view?.userInteractionEnabled = false
        self.sourceViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.exitPanGesture)

    }
}
```

Before setting menuViewController I set sourceViewController. So, here I am adding new gesture recognizer to my sourceViewController. Next, step is to disable this gesture recognize. When you close the menu disable it using this code:

```
 var presentingP:Bool!{
    didSet{
        if presentingP == true {
            // enable the gesture recognizer only when the view of menucontroller is presented

            self.exitPanGesture.view?.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }else{
            // disable gesture recognizer when menu is not presented
            self.exitPanGesture.view?.userInteractionEnabled = false
            isMenuVisible = false
        }
    }
}
```

PresentingP is boolean value which shows when menu is opened and closed!