# Reduce the UIView size without cutting its content

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

I'm drawing in a `UIView` with frame property (x, y, width, height) values `[0, 0, 350, 700]`

I want make this a subview of a view with frame values `[50, 50, 140, 140]`

I want to reduce the size of the first view without cropping the contents.

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func btnSignPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    for i in 1...drawTag {
        if (i == drawTag) {
            AddSignView = ACEDrawingView()
            AddSignView.tag = 1
            AddSignView.frame = ViewSignature.frame //where ViewSignature Frame is equal to view.frame
            ViewSignature.addSubview(AddSignView)
            DrawingViewCollection.append(AddSignView)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func btnSavepressed(_ sender: Any) {

    for i in 1...viewTag {
        if (i == viewTag) {
            let person = ZDStickerView()
            let gripFrame1 = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(140), height: CGFloat(140))
            let contentView = UIView(frame: gripFrame1)

            contentView.clipsToBounds = true
            contentView.addSubview(DrawingViewCollection[i - 1])
            contentView.clipsToBounds = true

            person.frame = gripFrame1
            person.stickerViewDelegate = self
            person.contentView = contentView
            //contentView;
            person.preventsPositionOutsideSuperview = true
            person.translucencySticker = true
            person.showEditingHandles()

            ZdStickerCollection.append(person)
            pdfCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Govind, do you want to not only make the view smaller but scale down the contents to be smaller and fit inside, or do you want the view contents to spill over the edge of the subview? I assume you want to actually scale the contents, and if so, see my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the `clipsToBounds` property and change your `UIView` size to your desired `width` and `height` value.

```
yourView.clipsToBounds = false;
yourView.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: That doesn't sound correct.https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds

Comment: Yes it works. Because by setting clipsToBounds to false you are telling your view to not to cut your child views which are even outside of your boundary.

Comment: But does it *scale* the contents, which is what he wants?

Comment: If he want to scale the view with respect to size change. The he should use AutoLayouts and change the constraints according to your need.

Comment: As he states he doesn't want to cut the subViews which are beyond the bounds of a UIView.

Comment: I assumed he wants to shrink the contents and leave them the same, but if he really wants the image hanging out over the edge of the view then your answer is right. If he wants to scale it he can use autolayout constraints or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475573/how-to-change-the-scale-of-view